# How to calculate Cohen's effect size f squared for multiple linear regression?

Tags: multiple-regression, r-squared, effect-size

For hypothesis testing, do I need to look at $R^2$ of the model (multiple linear regression) when I want to calculate Cohen's effect size $F^2$ ($F^2$= $\frac{R^2}{(1-R^2))}$? I heard that P-value is not sufficient for hypothesis testing alone.